# Creating 1 Windows image with multiple drivers for different hardware

Tags: windows-server-2008, imagex, answer-file

We have two different computer builds. One AMD Chipset with FirePro graphics card. The other Intel Chipset with NVIDIA graphics card . If I include a answerfile for the Windows image, will it know what graphics driver to use based off the hardware? Is there a better option using imagex to create image other then using an answer file?